# exporting to csv converts text to date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, variables

From Python i want to export to csv format a dataframe

The dataframe contains two columns like this

[image]

So when i write this :

```
df['NAME'] = df['NAME'].astype(str) # or .astype('string')
df.to_csv('output.csv',index=False,sep=';')
```

The excel output in csv format returns this :
[image: image2]

and reads the value "MAY8218" as a date format "may-18" while i want it to be read as "MAY8218".

I've tried many ways but none of them is working. I don't want an alternative like putting quotation marks to the left and the right of the value.

Thanks.

Comment: That is not python/pandas but rather Excel's fault.  Check the text of output.csv in a text editor.

Comment: I don't get it but is there a way from python to unable excel to read cells as date  automatically ?

Comment: In Excel --> Data --> From Text/CSV --> Choose File --> Data Type Detection (set to do not detect).. Alternatively, Libre Office has an import tool that makes this dead simple

Answer (score 3):

If you want to export the dataframe to use it in excel just export it as xlsx. It works for me and maintains the value as string in the original format.

```
df.to_excel('output.xlsx',index=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

The CSV format is a *text* format. The file contains no hint for the type of the field. The problem is that Excel has the worst possible support for CSV files: it assumes that CSV files always use its own conventions when you try to read one. In short, one Excel implementation can only read correctly what it has written...

That means that you cannot prevent Excel to interpret the csv data the way it wants, at least when you *open* a csv file. Fortunately you have other options:

- *import* the csv file instead of opening it. This time you have options to configure the way the file should be processed.
- use LibreOffice calc for processing CSV files. LibreOffice is a little behind Microsoft Office on most points *except for csv file handling* where it has an excellent support.

Comment: much better than my comment!